# iPad coding app that allows code folding

Tags: ipad, folding

I could get flamed for asking this, but here goes anyway...

Does anyone know of a coding app that you can use on an iPad and that allows you to fold your code? I can't find one.

I'll delete the question quite happily if it's judged inappropriate for SO :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Xcode**

You can fold code, by highlighting over the start of a code block, and selecting the black arrow.

[image: Xcode code folding]

There is also a menu providing more options (with keyboard shortcuts)

[image: Folding menu in Xcode]

**TextWrangler/BBEdit**

Same principle, but you don't have the integrated development environment that Xcode has

[image: TextWrangler/BBEdit Code Folding]

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant an app you can use on an iPad, not one to create iPad apps :) Xcode and TextWrangler don't have an iPad version, as far as I can see. (Could be wrong, of course.)

Comment: But +1 anyway for a great answer to what my question might have been asking :)